# Why do these fonts get blurry on rotation?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, antialiasing

I have this personal little website I wrote with the help of [typeplate](http://typeplate.com/).

The website is very simple and looks like this:
[image]
**The link to the site is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80497/htmlTesting/TestStuff/index.html)**

The 3 square rotate slightly, constantly.

I have a couple of problems, different by browser:

1. In Chrome/Internet Explorer - The fonts get blurry on rotation
2. In Firefox - The lines get jagged and ugly on rotation

Is this due to anti aliasing? Not sure how to fix this. especially the font problem is annoying to me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, this is due to anti-aliasing on the custom fonts. No, you cannot fix this from CSS regrettably.

Comment: Maybe using the new [`will-change`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/) css property?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the transform:perspective property which is known for limiting these problems.

```
#rotated-element {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1px) rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: perspective(1px) rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Your texts should display better. Be careful not to add the property to IE and Opera as it might break things.

More info and techniques here: 
http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/